Why are lists<T> so much slower than vector<T*>?
The other day, I was playing with this quickbench: https://quick-bench.com/q/fwF5nkc4ORmYwSXSoVy2d-ekN5U
Basically, the code just measures the time it takes to iterate and sum over different cases : std::vector<int> (reference point), std::vector<Foo>, std::vector<Foo*>, std::list<Foo> and a custom basic implementation of a list.
The Foo struct is just a value at the beginning and then some garbage to make it the size of a cache line.
struct Foo {
  int value;
  int garbage[15];
};

The results look like the following:

While I understand the difference between the reference case (std::vector<int>) and the other ones, I am a bit surprised by the difference between the vector<I clearly don't get why the list cases (especially std::list...) are so slow compared to the std::vector<Foo*> case.
Why is it so much slower to follow random pointers versus dereferencing the same random pointers with the main difference (I think) being that the addresses are stored contiguously in memory (but the adresses themselves should be as random as the list ones) ?

One thing is that list<Foo> adds a pair of pointers to the node size, making it two cache lines.

@BoP Actually, the perf is also horrible with just a list<int>. In that case, even with the two pointers, that would still be fitting in one cache line, wouldn't it ? That clearly has an impact though

In the case of a list, the CPU also needs to wait for the current node to be retrieved from cache/RAM before it can determine the next memory location to load. In the case of the vector, all pointer to memory locations that need to be loaded are right there next to each other and the operations can be parallelized (on the CPU level).

@user17732522 Oh, that's probably the main reason, now that would make more sense

What operations are you doing on the container?   Depending on operations you are performing, you may be comparing operations of specified O(1) complexity on the vector with operations that have O(n) complexity on the list.   Another set of operations would result in std::list performing better (e.g. if the operations you pick are specified as O(1) on the list but O(n) on the vector).

@cmourglia If you want a more specific analysis, I would recommend adding the relevant parts of the assembly generated by the compiler to the question and to tag x86/x86-64. There are some users on this site specializing in these performance details of the architecture/CPU.

@Peter Only traversing the containers and reading the value. I know this is not a good case for a list, but my question is not about the relevance of using this or that container, only why the traversal and fetching of a vector or random adresses is magnitude faster than the traversal and fetching of a list, which felt very similar to be (before user17732522 hint)

Reading lists results in pointer chasing which is known to be horribly inefficient, especially on large lists because they do not fit in the fast cache or even not in cache at all. The addresses can become unpredictable over time because of memory diffusion cause by the allocation pattern. The worst thing comes from the lack of concurrent loads while memory latency is big. DRAM access can takes dozens of ns (so this is the time of each pointer node fetch if the list is not in cache) like 60-100 ns. Meanwhile dozens of nodes can be loaded concurrently in a vector (limited by the bandwidth).

"the difference between the vector<I clearly don't get" -- Between the vector and what? It looks like some words got cut.

"Only traversing the containers and reading the value".   By design std::vector, and its iterators, traverse elements more efficiently than std::list.   For other operations (e.g. inserting elements into the middle of a container with a lot of elements) std::list will leave std::vector in the dust.   It is not possible - within current state of knowledge - to design/implement a container with all operations optimised.

Bjarne Explaining the problems: https://youtu.be/YQs6IC-vgmo


Why is it so much slower to follow random pointers

Because accessing randomly distributed memory is about the slowest thing you can do in a computer program.
That's just it; your processor gets a memory address, needs to fetch that memory, and fetching memory simply takes a lot of time. Due to the sequential nature of a list, your CPU can't do anything based on the next node while the current node is still being fetched, so linked list data structures are quite close to worst-case access paradigms in terms of memory/cache bandwidth, and also in terms of CPU pipelines.

with the main difference (I think) being that the addresses are stored contiguously in memory

CPUs (and also compilers) can reorder things if the next step doesn't inherently depend on results from the previous one. So, your CPU can hide a lot of memory latency by already starting to look up the next memory location (potentially multiple, actually) while waiting for memory from the first to be retrieved.
With a list, that's impossible, because the next memory location to fetch isn't known until the currently requested memory has been fetched, and the pointer to the next node is known.
The raw std::vector<int> of course has no such problems, and by virtue of the values being contiguous in memory, you also minimize memory bandwidth (you only fetch the data you actually need, and you use all of each cacheline, typically 64 B, which is the granularity at which memory is fetched). Bonus point for that fetching then also directly being in the right order: that makes it possible for the compiler to directly fetch the memory into SIMD registers, to do multiple additions at once (if your processor has AVX2, that'd be 8 additions in one instruction, with AVX512, up to 16 additions per instruction. If you have an x86 PC, you almost certainly have AVX2, if you have a modern AMD CPU, AVX512 will be blazingly fast).
Why your custom list is faster than the std::list, I don't really know, but my guess would be on extra sanity checks. You might want to build (with debug symbols, but optimized) run your code locally on your machine and profile it (e.g. with perf if you're on Linux).

Good answer. "Why your custom list is faster than the std::list, I don't really know," the next pointer and value are close to each other and typically on the same cache line. This should not be the case in the std::list one : AFAIK the pointer is at the end. This does not mean std::list are slower since the fetched items could be close to the end of the structure. It is just bad luck for std::list in this case. The custom list would be slower if we add padding in the beginning of the structure rather than the end. The rule of thumb is to make small structures in this case.

Another thing which is certainly not the main issue is that std::list are doubly linked while their structure is simply linked. The former take more space (and the next pointer might even be stored after the prev one -- so even further). Comparing their own structure to std::forward_list is probably better than std::list

I did not know that CPU was able to request different "random" memory addresses in parallel, but now that makes sense and that indeed explains a lot.
For the custom list vs std::list, indeed the next pointer being after the data might explain a lot.

@cmourglia we should be a bit careful here: that's a feature that's not inherently guaranteed, and not every CPU can, and it doesn't help you very much, anyways, here. What helps is that while you're fetching memory for the next iteration of your sum, the last sum can actually still be executed, because nothing of that "looking up the next memory address, and fetching it, advancing the read pointer" depends on the actual number you're adding – that addition only needs to be done when you want to add the next number. So, the trick here is that the next memory address to be fetched is already…

… known at the time when the current fetch finishes, so that the fetching can happen right after, with zero gap. That way, you always keep the memory controller working, doing useful transfers, and that's the thing that is the absolute bottleneck here. In the linked list case, the first transfer finishes, then the next has to be done (your list node wraps a Foo object that is exactly one cache line in size, so even best case, you need one cache line just for the node "header", then a second one for the integer you care about), then when that is finished, the next node might be fetched…

… so your list has to have at least twice the total memory transfer. That's quite costly, and the nonsequential nature of addressing makes it even more costly, because modern CPUs have caches, which would work quite nicely to make the memory fetches faster, but that won't work if you're shuffling a large load of random addresses through – the node headers won't reliably be still in cache when they're needed.

Nitpick: the memory being accessed isn't randomly distributed. It's still going to be quite linear in this case because the list is created by an uninterrupted sequence of push_back and the default allocation is almost certainly not going to randomly allocate memory. The problem is CPU stalling, not so much memory latency.

Example here.

@PasserBy I blew up your example a bit (instead of 20 iterations, I do 1<<26, and instead of printing stuff, I get a value from the struct and do calculation on it), and as expected: roughly 45% cache misses. Sure, the default allocator will not pick a random page for every node, but it can't do wonders for anything that's large enough that someone would care about performance!

@MarcusMüller I'm not a hardware person, but I'm guessing that's still not a problem of random accesses causing prefetching to fail. When you do one addition per cache line, you run into bandwidth problems.
